# How does Python 3 store local variables?

Tags: python-3.x

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
def foo(self):
    i = 4
    self.bar(__something_which_holds_foo_variables__)
    print(i) # prints 8
    print(j) # prints 2

def bar(self, vars):
    vars.j = 2
    vars.i = vars.i * vars.j
```

Access all local variables from a method from another method.

Using nested methods and `nonlocal` variables is not an option, as `foo` and `bar` may be in different modules.
Passing variables by names is not an option, too, as `bar()` may produce other variables which I'd like to use later as locals in `foo()`. Moreover, potentially `bar()` may use a lot of variables from `foo()`.

Is it possible to achieve this and why such idea may be good or bad?

Comment: Your use of `self` there kind of implies you're using a `class`... If that's the case - you should just store the things that are common to all methods on the instance of the class...

Comment: In the example above, yes. But I explicitely specified, that `foo` and `bar` may be in different module. Anyway, I solved the problem in a different manner

Answer (score 0):

Just use (for different modules):

```
def bar():
    global modulename.i
```

Or if it is in a class then:

```
def bar():
    global modulename.classname.i
```

This idea could be simpler, because you could just make `bar(...)` a return definition, and let it return the new i and j in some form of a tuple.

Comment: You don't need `global` to read stuff, just to *modify* it. However, having your functions rely on values from other modules like this (unless they are constants) or  have them modify such values can make for hard to find bugs. If `modulename.i` is changed, `bar()` might suddenly return another value... It is generally a good idea to make imputs to a function *explicit* by making them parameters. The other way around is that any call to `bar()` might modify `modulename.i` if `global` is used, which would then influence the result of all other code that used `modulename.i`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, :)